# Windows Defender Firewall blocking Windows Defender Antivirus updates

Tags: windows-10, firewall, anti-virus

I want to use Windows Defender Firewall to block outbound connections. I've configured it to block outbound connections and added a rule to allow the browsers (i.e. allow-list). However Windows Defender Antivirus then fails to download antivirus updates.("Protection definition update failed. Error code: 80240438"). When I remove the outboud connection block from the firewall, virus updates download OK again.
I've tried adding a rule to allow the Defender executable MpCmdRun.exe - this is suggested elsewhere as a solution - but this does not fix the problem.
What rule(s) do I need to add to allow antivirus updates ? I'm guessing there's some other program or service that needs to be allowed through the firewall.
Windows Defender Firewall comes with a set of standard rules which allow various OS applications and services through the firewall. I am very surprised that there isn't a rule in the standard rule-set that allows Defender Antivirus.

Problem exhibits on both Windows 10 and Windows 11.
Home network; ADSL connection, no router firewall, no proxy and nothing exotic about the network.
Thanks in advance!